# Change global variables by js function

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I wanna change a group of scrolling images by clicking on button. question here is how to change the global variables by these function
please see the attached codes,

I wanna initiate the stack() function when onload and change the scrolling images set by onclick;

Should I add an onload event and seperately call the stack() funtions, only using the local var?
thanks,
Joe

```
var images = imagest;

function softtissue(){

    var images = imagest;
}

function bone(){

    var images = imagebone;

}
function lung(){
    var images = imagelung;
}
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack);
```

```js
// how to use the funciton on line 94
// for questions email felix@demont.is

var images10 = [
"https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"

];

var imagesbone = [
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"
];

var imageslung = [
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg",
  "https://igu3ss.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/chess_king_4.jpg",
"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG/130px-Chess_piece_-_Black_queen.JPG", "https://asmoodle.asmadrid.org/blog/s16240/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2014/12/protourney_knight_black_400.jpg",
"https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/x/chess-knight-white-background-29811348.jpg",
"http://cdn.craftsy.com/upload/3703789/pattern/115774/full_7439_115774_ChessKnightMachineEmbroideryDesign_1.jpg"
];

function ImageStack(options) {

  var self = this;

  self.img_array = options.images;

  self.stack = document.createElement('div');
  self.stack.style.overflow = 'auto';
  self.stack.style.maxWidth = '100%';
  self.stack.style.height = options.height;
  self.stack.style.width = options.width;
  self.stack.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
  self.stack.style.position = 'relative';

  var typeRegex = /(\D+)/
  var sizeType = options.height.match(typeRegex)[0]

  var numberRegex = /(\d+)/
  self.height_number = Number(options.height.match(numberRegex)[0])

  self.wrapper = document.createElement('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < self.img_array.length; i++) {

    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.src = self.img_array[i];

    image.style.display = 'none';
    image.style.position = 'absolute';
    image.style.width = options.width;
    image.style.height = options.height;
    image.style.top = 0;
    image.style.left = 0;
    image.dataset.iid = i;

    self.wrapper.appendChild(image);

  }

  self.image_elements = self.wrapper.querySelectorAll('img');

  self.scrollobject = document.createElement('div');
  self.scrollobject.style.width = '100%';
  self.scrollobject.style.position = 'absolute';
  self.scrollobject.style.zIndex = '2';
  self.img_count = (self.img_array.length > 15) ? self.img_array.length : 15;
  self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_count * self.height_number);

  self.scrollobject.style.height = self.scrollobject_height + sizeType;

  self.scrollUpdate = function(e) {

    self.height_number = self.stack.getBoundingClientRect().height
    self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_count * self.height_number);

    var sT = self.stack.scrollTop
    var hn05 = self.img_array.length - 1
    var hh = (self.scrollobject_height - self.height_number) / hn05
    scrollval = Math.floor(sT / (hh))

    self.currentimg = self.image_elements[scrollval].src

    self.stack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + self.currentimg + ')';

  }

  self.stack.addEventListener('scroll', self.scrollUpdate);

  self.currentimg = self.image_elements[0].src
  self.stack.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + self.currentimg + ')';



  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var stackRect = self.stack.getBoundingClientRect()

    console.log(stackRect)

    self.height_number = stackRect.height
    self.scrollobject_height = Math.floor(0.1 * self.img_array.length * self.height_number);

    self.stack.style.width = stackRect.width + 'px'
    self.stack.style.eight = stackRect.width + 'px'
  })



  self.stack.appendChild(self.wrapper);
  self.stack.appendChild(self.scrollobject);

  return self.stack;

}

/*problems here*/
/*global var*/
var images = images10;

/*local var*/
function softtissue() {
  var images = images10;
}

function bone() {

  var images = imagesbone;

}

function lung() {
  var images = imageslung;

}


/*how to switch the local var in global function*/
var stack = new ImageStack({
  images: images,
  height: '512px',
  width: '512px'
});
document.querySelector('.example').appendChild(stack);
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="softtissue" type="button" onclick="softtissue();return false" class="button">
  Soft Tissue</button>
  <button id="bone" type="button" onclick="bone(); return false;" class="button">
 Bone</button>
  <button id="lung" type="button" onclick="lung(); return false" class="button">
 Lung</button>
</div>

<div class="example">
</div>
```

Comment: I will add a demo soon

Comment: Why you are declaring new variable inside functions?

Comment: The issue is actually you are creating new variables inside the functions (by keyword `var`, so then the global ones are replaced-overridden by these local variables (local ones are valid in scope of function, or more exactly in scope of curly brackets-  `{` and `}`

Comment: I think you are new to javascript, please read this documentation related to Global and local scope.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch04s03.html

Comment: Images could be a parameter you pass to a function that returns a new ImageStack. Then you can remove the 3 other functions and the global variable altogether.

Answer (score 1):

`var images = imagebone;` never changes the global but it initializes a local variable. It creates a local variable `images` inside the function. You shouldn't use `var` inside functions

```
function softtissue(){
    images = imagest;
}
function bone(){
    images = imagebone;
}
function lung(){
    images = imagelung;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use `images` as a parameter to a general function instead of a separate function specific to the image. That way you can add unlimited amounts of images without the need to write an extra function for each image.

So inside the `change_image()` function, the correct image string just gets taken from the button clicked, instead of there being a function to set some global variable.

```js
// ImageStack mockup
function ImageStack( config ) {
  this.images = config.images;
  this.height = config.height;
  this.width = config.width;
}
ImageStack.prototype.node = function() {
  return document.createElement( 'div' ).appendChild( document.createTextNode( this.images ));
};
// click event for all the buttons
function change_image( event ) {
  var image_type = event.target.getAttribute( 'data-type' );
  var stack = new ImageStack({
    images: `image${ image_type }`,
    height: '512px',
    width: '512px'
  });
  render( stack.node() );
}
// render function.
// Could be inside the click event, but I would prefer seperate functions.
function render( image ) {
  document.querySelector('.example').appendChild( image );
}

Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( 'button' )).forEach(function( button ) {
  button.addEventListener( 'click', change_image );
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <button data-type="st">ST</button>
  <button data-type="bone">BONE</button>
  <button data-type="lung">LUNG</button>
</nav>
<section class="example"></section>
```

**EDIT:**

Since the question text got updated and no longer includes the line `Or is there a better approach?`, this answer might seem weird.

Comment: Thanks a lot Shilly. actually I wanna switch stacks of different images

Comment: Hopefully, I can do it by adding a window.onload() at the beginning which call the image and stack function

Comment: Yes indeed. I didn't have the ImageStack code when I wrote this example, so it was not clear that the ImageStack includes multiple images in an array. What you can do is create one object and use `imagebone`, `imagelung`, etc as the objects keys for the arrays holding the urls. That way you still only need one variable `images` and you can select the correct urls as `images[ image_type ]` or something. In the future you could then update the code to use a config file in json or something to arrive back at the point where you do not need to edit JS code when adding images.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is changing the varibility of the image

adding variability ="hidden" in the imagestack and after creating these three boxes, onclickfunction onlick choose which one to show

Comment: or you can use block/none as well